# populating a dojo dijit combo box

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo

I have  dijit combo box that is decalared in the cust.Html page  as follows:

```
<div class="CustDijit">
<div class="formContainer">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" data-dojo-attach-point="searchFormDijit">
        <table cellspacing="5" style="width:100%; height: 49px;">
            <tr>
                <td>


                    <select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" name="state"  data-dojo-id="comboBoxID2"  id="stateInput" data-dojo-attach-point="idResultItemsCB"/>                       
                    <br />
                    Enter Attribute Value:<input id="searchText" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="name:'searchText',trim:true,required:true,style:'width:100%;'"
                    />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


</div>
```

`

Now this html page is being created as a widget in the js code as shown below...Its here i want to populate the combobox. I have function created to pupulate the combo box but as i am very new to The dojotoolkit and dijits hence having a tuff time..Can some one please guide me as what i am doing wrong in the code below.

```
define([
'dojo/_base/declare',
'dijit/_WidgetBase',
'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
"dijit/registry",
'dijit/form/Form',
'dijit/form/FilteringSelect',
'dijit/form/ValidationTextBox',
'dijit/form/Button',   
"dijit/layout/ContentPane",
"dojo/store/Memory",
"dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore",
'dojox/grid/DataGrid',
'dijit/TooltipDialog',
'esri/tasks/query',
'esri/tasks/QueryTask',
'esri/config',
'dojo/store/Memory',
'dojo/_base/lang',
'dojo/_base/array',
'dojo/text!./Cust/templates/cust.html',
"dojo/parser",
'dijit/form/ComboBox',
"dijit/form/FilteringSelect",
 "dojo/domReady!"

 ], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, registry,   Form, FilteringSelect, ValidationTextBox, Button, ContentPane, Memory, ItemFileReadStore, DataGrid, TooltipDialog, query, QueryTask, esriConfig, Memory, lang, array, custTemplate, parser, ComboBox, FilteringSelect,dom) {

//anonymous function to load CSS files required for this module
(function () {
    var css = [require.toUrl("gis/dijit//css/cust.css")];
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0),
        link;
    for (var i = 0, il = css.length; i < il; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("link");
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.href = css[i].toString();
        head.appendChild(link);
    }
    parser.parse();
} ());

// Main cust dijit
var  Cust = declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], 
{
    widgetsInTemplate: true,
    templateString: custTemplate,
    map: null,
    defaultTitle: null,
    queryTask: null,
    query: null,
    map: null,
    self: null,
    _store1: null,
   _selectorOne: null,
    postCreate: function () {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this.queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask(this.queryTaskURL);
        this.query = new esri.tasks.Query();
        this.query.outSpatialReference = this.map.spatialReference;
        this.query.returnGeometry = true;
        this.query.outFields = ["id", "Custname", "Status"];
        self.cmboxlayer();

                    this.populateResultsIntoComboBox(Memory);

    },

    populateResultsIntoComboBox: function (Memory) {
        var stateStore = new Memory({
            data: [
                { name: "Alabama", id: "AL" },
                { name: "Alaska", id: "AK" },
                { name: "Arizona", id: "AZ" },
                { name: "Arkansas", id: "AR" },
                { name: "California", id: "CA" },
                { name: "Colorado", id: "CO" },
                { name: "Connecticut", id: "CT" },
                { name: "Delaware", id: "DE" }
            ]
        });

        var comboBoxDigit = registry.byId("stateInput");           
        //on(comboBoxDigit, "change", lang.hitch(this, 'comboBoxSelectionChangedEventHandler'));
        comboBoxDigit.store = stateStore;
        comboBoxDigit.searchAttr = "title";
        comboBoxDigit.set('value', stateStore.data[0].title);
    }

});
return Search;
    });
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, you never define self=this in your postCreate function. Did you define self somewhere else in the widget instantiation phase?

I also noticed you named your template, 'custTemplate', and used 'searchTemplate' to define your templateString instead.

I've made a stripped down version of your code work at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/n4jF7/

The only thing I can think of is if you didn't set parseOnLoad to be true:

```
parseOnLoad: true
```

or if you didn't call parser.parse to parse the template.

Comment: Thank You for the response richard...I have changed my code a wee bit but still struggling to populate the combo box..  I have edited my original question.. Please check .

Comment: Edited my answer to highlight another problem. Also, could you post the errors that you have?

Comment: Richard Sorry but forgot to change that in the code above..The issue you just pointed was resolved by me long back..There are no errors. Its just that the combo box is not poulated.  The function populateResultsIntoComboBox is not doing it.

Comment: Thank you so much Richard. You made my day. The isue was with the way data was being stored in to the combo box. You example in fiddle showed me the right path.  Thank you